# How do I put GIF/PNG/... image on a BitBtn in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm using Delphi 2007. How can I put a GIF/PNG image on a BitBtn component? (Preferably, with alpha transparency supported)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PngComponents](http://www.thany.org/article/18/Delphi_components) pack has a component named PngBitBtn wich can display correctly PNG's with alpha transparency. They are somewhat old, but they can be installed under Delphi 2007 with a little work.

Comment: PngComponents can still be downloaded from the [Wayback Machine here](https://web.archive.org/web/20071214214235/http://thany.org/article/32/PngComponents).

Answer (score 2):

Use a graphics program like Photoshop (or something less expensive) to convert the images to bitmaps.  BitBtns don't accept GIF or PNG images.

Comment: But then transparency becomes an issue.

Comment: From memory, Delphi had a little trick where it considered one of the corner pixels (top-left? bottom-left?) to be the "transparent" colour. Provided you leave that pixel as the colour you want to be transparent it should work, even for BMPs.

Comment: It's the bottom left pixel, but it's colour-key transparency only. If you want alpha-blended transparency, you need to use PNG in Delphi 2009.

Comment: For conversion, you can use Paint.NET or IrfanView. Both are free.

Comment: Weird - I see a lot of replies talking about alpha transparency, but I didn't get that from his question. He mentions GIF too - does GIF have an alpha channel? I don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

PNG support is only fully supported by Delphi 2009.  There is a freeware package (licensed as MPL 1.1) named [GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33) which will allow you to load the images at design time/runtime, but you will not get the alpha blended transparency on the button in Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 0):

PNGimage, which is included in Delphi 2009k, should do the job. If we can find it.